# What does it mean to say the action is "completely determined" by gauge invariance?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, action, gauge-invariance

When we are considering a gauge theory with some action, what does it mean to say "all the terms in the action are completely determined by gauge invariance"?

Letting $G$ denote the gauge theory group, is the statement meaning that this action is the most general possible action that can have $G$ as it's gauge group? Or is it a statement regarding the fields of this theory, that they are somehow determined by their gauge invariance? I have seen this phrase used a few times now, and it is unclear to me what is meant by it.

Comment: Seen this phrase a few times where?

Comment: I remember someone saying this based on Noether's second theorem. Is that related?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this means that the Lagrangean is determiend by gauge invariance *plus some general requirements and conventions of QFT regarding the possible terms in the action*. In particular, this implies canonical kinetic terms and no couplings of negative mass dimension.

Thus, schematically, if your theory contains scalars $\phi$, fermions $\psi$ and gauge fields $A_\mu$, you will have the kinetic terms $D_\mu\phi D^\mu\phi$, $\bar\psi\not D\psi$ and $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$, mass terms ($m^2 \phi^2$, $m\bar\psi\psi$), cubic and quartic terms ($a\phi^3$, $\lambda \phi^4$) and Yukawa couplings $\bar\psi\psi\,\phi$. The gauge grouop and representations will then determine what the covariant derivatives are, which of these terms actually are allowed, and which couplings you need to describe the action.